# Extracting a DC value from a sum of sinusoids

Tags: filters, cosine

I guess it might be a basic questions but here it goes anyways.

How could I extract a DC value from a sum of sinusoids, i.e.:

$$v(t) =\widetilde{v_{dc}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(\omega_nt+\phi_n)$$

I tried using low pass filters in Matlab or just mean of the signal but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'd also like to have a mathematical way of expressing this.

Comment: How can you have sum of sinusoids upt to infinity in MATLAB? Can you share your code with us?

Comment: First apply a DC-block (a notch) then subtract the signals...

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about your application? I get the sense that what you are trying to do is some form of [envelope detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector) (?). A DC is just that, the mean of a signal. At $f=0$, the trigonometric function stays at $1$, which "weighs" all signal samples equally during the summation step. This is complemented by the subsequent $\frac{1}{N}$ and that's basically an average. A constant value. Is this what you are after? If not, then what sort of time basis do you have?

Comment: @learner Well, it was gust to generalise. It's not obviously an infinite sum but I have a mix of bunch of signals and I just need to find a part of it. I could share the code but the signals come from a Simulink and I might have to go too deep into details in that case.

Comment: @Fat32 I was also thinking about doing something so I might try that but I might also have a signal at 1Hz here and there so I would have to gave something highly selective, right?

Comment: @A_A The application is measuring output impedance of a diode rectifier. Basically yes, I am looking for an envelope. What do you mean when you ask me about the time basis? Sorry if my questions are basic but I'm not really on par with signal processing.

Comment: No worries. If you are really going for envelope extraction, then it's probably better to update the question to reflect that. You will get much better quality responses. You can try a moving average filter which would basically give you a "running mean" of your signal over a certain time basis (e.g. mean over a sliding 50ms window). There are better methods for envelope detection though...

Comment: @A_A Moving average filter worked! Thanks! Could you just explain me one more thing. I've noticed that both of these codes work in the same way but I don't understand the difference:

    fil_length=2000;  
    b=[1 zeros(1,fil_length-1) -1]/fil_length;  
    a=[1 -1 zeros(1,fil_length-1)];  

   fil_length = 2000; 
   b = (1/fil_length)*ones(1,fil_length);
   a = 1;

Sorry, I don't know how to input code in Stack.

Comment: Can I please ask that you update the question with all of this information that we have been talking about in the comments and I (or someone else) will provide a "proper" response to it. This is to make sure that we close questions properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with linear filtering as others have suggested or do something nonlinear.

The sinusoids are symmetric around zero so if the exact dc value is subtracted prior to a hard clipper like Matlab’s sign() function, the, leaky integral of the hard clipped  time series would be zero, which means that it can act as the error of a feedback loop.

This sort of thing was done a lot by circuitry in older systems to compensate for the dc offsets that occurred in A/D converters that operated in a wide temperature range.

The integrator can be a linear leaky integrator, or a counter depending on how you implement it